# How to sort through an associated attribute on two levels at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a simple ruby question I believe. In my app, I have Product model that has_many Reviews. Each Review has an attribute of an "overall" rating which is an integer.

What I want to do is display the top ten Products based on the average of their overall ratings. I've already gotten this to work, BUT, I also want to sort Products that have the SAME overall rating by a secondary aggregate attribute, which would be how MANY reviews that Product has. Right now, if I have 3 products with the same average overall rating, they seem to be displayed in random order.

So far my code is:

## Controller

```
@best = Product.has_reviews.get_best_products(10)
```

## Product Model

```
scope :has_reviews, joins{reviews.outer}.where{reviews.id != nil}

def self.get_best_products(number)
  sorted = self.uniq
  sorted = sorted.sort { |x, y| y.reviews.average("overall").to_f <=> x.reviews.average("overall").to_f }
  sorted.first(number)
end
```

I've tried this for my model code:

```
def self.get_best_products(number)
  sorted = self.uniq.sort! { |x, y| x.reviews.count.to_f <=> y.reviews.count.to_f }
  sorted = sorted.sort { |x, y| y.reviews.average("overall").to_f <=> x.reviews.average("overall").to_f }
  sorted.first(number)
end
```

...but it does not do what I want it to do. I am just iterating through the @best array using each in my view.

---UPDATE

OK now I am trying this:

Controller:

```
@best = Product.get_best_products(6)
```

Model:

```
def self.get_best_products(number)
  self.joins{reviews}.order{'AVG(reviews.overall), COUNT(reviews)'}.limit(number)
end
```

But I am getting this error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "reviews" ...
```

I am using the Squeel gem btw to avoid having direct SQL code in the model.

----UPDATE 2

Now I added the 'group' part to my method but I am still getting an error:

```
def self.get_best_products(number)
  self.joins{reviews}.group('product.id').order{'AVG(reviews.overall), COUNT(reviews)'}.limit(number)
end
```

I get this error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product"
LINE 1: ...eviews"."product_id" = "products"."id" GROUP BY product.i...
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do the sorting in the database? I.e. use `order` instead of `sort`.

Comment: It should be `products.id` instead of `product.id`. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

**product.rb**

```
scope :best_products, (lambda do |number|
  joins(:reviews).order('AVG(reviews.overall), COUNT(reviews)').limit(number)
)
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
Product.best_products(10)
```

This makes sure everything happens in the database, so you won't get records you don't need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried implementing it verbatim and also the way I did it in the update to my question. Both ways yielded the same error. I tried doing joins{reviews.outer} but it did not solve the problem either. Can you please tell what is going wrong?

Comment: Try adding `.group('product.id')`

Comment: If you're going to use `group` you also have to use `select`.

Comment: Can you please give me an example for how to use group and select together?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right here is my idea of how I would do it:

As `products` has many `reviews` and `reviews` has an `overall` attribute I would add a `reviews_counter` column to the products table that will increment with each added review, this way you'll be able to gain a little more db performance as you don't have to `count` all the `products` reviews to get the most reviewed one.

Now you'll get the products ordered by `reviews_counter`:

`@best_products = Products.order("reviews_counter desc")`

and next you'll get the `reviews` for each product ordered by `overall`:

```
<% for prod in @best_products %>
  <%= prod.reviews.order("overall desc") %> # can do all this or more in helper
<% end %>
```

also ordering this way, if you have 3 reviews with the same overall you can one more `order()` statement and sort it by `name` or `id` or whatever you like so they don't display in random order.

This is just my idea of how I would do it, I worked recently on an app that required something similar and we just added a counter_field to our model, it's not illegal to do so :)

p.s. it's not very clear for me how many records you would want to display for each so you'll just need to add `.limit(5)` for exemple to get only the first 5 reviews of a product.

Comment: But if I add a limit to the controller code like this, wouldn't I be only getting the top n products by their reviews count and then sorting that array of n records in the view by the overall rating? What if I want to prioritize the overall rating first and then only sort products that have the same overall average rating by their number of reviews?

Comment: right, now the question is more clear to me, I'll think about it and will update it if I can

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help with this